# Aliasing in Python even though under Nyquist rate

Tags: python, signal-processing

From my understanding, the following code creates a 1 second long sine wave sampled at 256 Hz, meaning a Nyquist rate of 128 Hz. So if a sine wave is having a frequency of 100 Hz, it should not experience aliasing.

```
t = np.linspace(0,1,256)
x = np.sin(2*np.pi*100*t)
plt.plot(t,x)
```

However, the plot looks something like this, with what I believe is aliasing?

[image]

Is there anything I'm doing wrong? what's the reason for this?

Comment: Zoom in. The plot isn't showing anything useful at all

Comment: You're showing a 100hz signal with only 256 points.  Each full cycle of your sin wave gets two or three points on your graph.  What are you expecting the result to look like?

Comment: That's not aliasing.  You're seeing the top and bottom of every cycle of the 100Hz.  It doesn't look like a sine wave, because the sample rate is so low, but the frequency is there.  Aliasing would not show you all 100 peaks.

Comment: If you sample at greater than the Nyquist rate, then you can perfectly reconstruct your signal from the samples -- but not by calling `plot`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your code is incorrect. You are sampling at 255Hz, not 256. To fix,

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 256, endpoint=False)
```

OR

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 257)
```

Here is a zoomed-in version of your (corrected) plot, with the sine wave shown at a much higher sampling frequency:

```
t = np.linspace(0, 1, 256, endpoint=False)
x = np.sin(2 * np.pi * 100 * t)
plt.plot(t, x)
plt.plot(t2 := np.linspace(0, 1, 10000), np.sin(2 * np.pi * 100 * t2), 'r:')
```

[image]

You are getting at least one point per half-cycle, which means that you can estimate the true frequency meaningfully from this data. Here is a similar dataset sampled at exactly Nyquist (200Hz):

[image]

Sampling with a different phase will move the line up and down, but it won't allow you to find meaningful information about the input signal.

Aliasing looks like this (sampling at 45Hz):

[image]

Since the sampling frequency is so much lower than the signal frequency, you end up with an estimate that is much lower.